# PHP: How to properly destroy session, delete session data and unset session variables

Tags: php, session, session-variables, destroy

I am new to PHP sessions and am looking for some help with the following:

**I start a session on a page as follows which works as intended so far:**

```
session_start();
// ...
$_SESSION["User"]["login"] = "loggedIn";
$_SESSION["User"]["username"] = $email;
```

Now if a the user wants to log out I also want to destroy this session (incl. deleting its data and unsetting its variables etc.). When searching for guidelines on this I came across the following on the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/session_destroy) but **I am not sure how to apply this and I don't understand what the lines in the ini part really do**.

Can someone help me with this and maybe also provide some short explanations on this ?

**My current code to destroy the session:**

```
session_start();
// ...
$_SESSION = array();
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $_SESSION["User"]["login"] = "",
        $_SESSION["User"]["username"] = ""
    );
}
session_destroy();
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: unset($_SESSION) did try this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `PHP` manual says

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current
>   session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with
>   the session, or unset the session cookie

Checkout the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

You can use `unset($_SESSION);`

OR

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

This will also empty the `Session` datas

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is great ! In my case it can happen that one user is registered with two different email addresses for different purposes so I want to allow them to be able to log out from one email and then log in with another one without the need to close the browser. I would like to go with this approach so considering the above would I just use unset($_SESSION); for the variables and then session_destroy(); for the actual session ? What I want to make sure is that both the session and its variables are destroyed / deleted.

Comment: yes..definitely, you just have to use `unset` function and then `session_destroy()`. That will do the job

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to destroy $_SESSION, PHP Garbage Collector do this automatically.

Just set `$_SESSION["User"]["login"] = false` and everywhere you need to check user login, check

```
if ($_SESSION["User"]["login"]) {
    // do something
} else {
    echo "You don't have access";
}
```